# How to Run ROS2 Humble natively on Beagle Bone Blue?

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, beaglebone, beagle-bone, beagleboard

Could someone provide insight on how I'd go about running ROS2 Humble on BeagleBoneBlue?

Trying to natively run ROS2 on beaglbone blue hardware for robotics project. I haven't found materials that give me a clear understanding to date.

I've been able to boot ubuntu 18 on SD card to run ROS1 but there are issues with booting beaglebone blue with ubuntu 22.04 since there don't seem to be 32-bit implementations of ubuntu jammy (beaglebone blue is a 32-bit SOC).

Comment: the beaglebone blue is a linux SoC, right? so the process will be the same as any of the other Linux SoC's, as outlined on the ROS wiki: SSH in, clone, and proceed... potentially building from source since it's on RISC. Please visit that resource, and if you are still stuck, you can return with a specific and answerable problem.

Answer (score 0):

Install ROS 2 Humble in Docker - it will surprise you how easy

1_setup_docker_apt_repo.sh
2_install_docker_packages.sh
3_clone_ros_docker_images.sh
4_build_humble_desktop_container.sh
5_test_humble_desktop_container.md
6_build_humble_desktop_plus_container.sh

My scripts

https://github.com/slowrunner/pi5desk/tree/main/configs/docker

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful! 
I don't know why the question was closed. I have no control over keeping my own question open and seeking additional input from helpful contributors. Sad :/

Comment: It was closed by a vote in the moderation queue for "Needs details or clarity -- This question should include more details and clarify the problem." Your edit helps IMO.

Comment: woohoo! Thank you kind people! Appreciate the grace shown towards a newbie!